# Format date in GridView

Tags: vb.net

Please see the database DDL below:

```
create table datetest (datetime1 datetime)
insert into datetest values(getdate())
```

Please see the presentation code below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

     <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("datetime1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

The output on the page is: 11/04/2013 19:51:40, but the database value is: 2013-04-11 19:51:40.017 (notice the milliseconds are chopped off the first value).

I have looked into this and have found a number of posts on here, which suggest using EVAL and String.Format, but I have been unsuccessful.  How can I display milliseconds on the webpage?

I have tried the following code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%
Eval("datetime1").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") %>'></asp:Label>
```

However, I am prompted with an exception: "Conversion from string "dd/MM/yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Comment: What you mean by *have been unsuccessful*? Show the code you've tried.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, the code is in the question.

Comment: Show the one with `eval`, which you've been unsuccessful with.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I tried the code as per James's answer (before he posted the answer).  I have edited the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Eval` with additional format parameter instead of `Eval().ToString()` call:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
           Text='<%# Eval("datetime1", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I ask why you have put: "<% Eval" instead of "<%# Eval"?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datetime1").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Something like that should do it. If you need help with custom time formats, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

You do not need to do a template to change the format though, you can add `{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}` in the custom format property

Comment: Thanks.  When I add the code above it prompts an exception (cannot convert string to integer).